# How to add data attendees Google Calender API with python looping?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, google-api, fetch

I'm creating 'Calendar of Event' using Google Calendar API for my project. To add attendees to my specific event with python, the API needs the data in this format below.

This is the static and success

```
 'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
```

I want to fetch data from database and input email with looping "For" in python

```
      'attendees': [
        myCursor.execute("SELECT email from calendar;")
        records = myCursor.fetchall()
        for row in records:
        {'email': row[0]},
      ],
```

I got invalid syntax

How to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to something like this:

```
myCursor.execute("SELECT email from calendar;")
records = myCursor.fetchall()
attendees = [
    {'email': row[0]} for row in records
]
```

And then when constructing your dictionary the way you intended to, just say:

```
{
    ...
    'attendees': attendees,
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.